# How to match all domain extensions in content script (firefox)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, content-script

I need to match all domain extensions for a simple Firefox extension I am writing. For example, I need to the extension to run on:

- https://example.com
- https://example.org
- https://example.net

I do not want the extension to run on anything that isn't the 'example website, e.g.,

- https://water.com
- https://facebook.com
- https://google.com

This is important, in part, so that I do not need to get permission to access data on all website for my extension.

Notes:

- this is not a question about regular expressions matching per se (there appear to be different rules at play here; this is not a duplicate of [Regex Match Domain Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671419/regex-match-domain-extension))
- This is not a duplicate of [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613731/chrome-extension-run-on-all-google-domains-and-a-specific-page) (does not solve this issue)

Answer (score 6):

You have to specifiy all the individual domain names you want to match

```json
"matches": [
   "https://example.com/*",
   "https://example.org/*",
   "https://example.net/*"
]
```

**Important:** Do not forget the `/*` path at the end, it will not work without that.

Unfortunately it is not possible to have a pattern match for all top level domains (like `https://example.*/*`), since Firefox explicitly disallows such matches as mentioned in [Invalid match patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns#invalid_match_patterns)

This is because of the hierarchy of domain names (from right to left)

- `*.example.com` belongs to `*.com`
- `www.example.com` belongs to `*.example.com`

The closest you can get is `https://*/*`. Declaratively mention this to handle all hosts, but programatically filter out the hosts you need. I do see that you don't want to get permission for all websites, but there is no other way.